# Stop propagation of press event / prevent bubbling on React-Native app when modal is open

Tags: javascript, events, react-native

I currently work on a React-Native mobile application.

I have a `PanResponder` set on my main view. My main view creates a component that contains a `Modal`.

My issue is when the `Modal` is open, the `PanResponder` which is below the modal (in the main view) still responds of the swipe events, and I'm trying to block them.

I tried to create a `PanResponder` in the `Modal` itself to block the one behind, but it doesn't work.

**MainView.js**

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <View {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
            {...}
            <SubView />
        </View>
    )
}
```

**SubView.js**

```
componentWillMount() {
    // Tentative of blocking the main view PanResponder
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <Modal transparent {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
            {...}
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

I'd like to avoid to change the `PanResponder` set on the main view, I don't want it to be aware if there is a modal open or not.

Do you know of a good solution to stop the propagation of events?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your main view pan responder code as well?

Comment: I edited the post with what it looks like.

Comment: Did you tried setting onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture to false on parent view. Maybe react native is not clear about this. But as per http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#capture-shouldset-handlers if onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture returns true in parent view. Parent will capture the touch. And onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture internally sets onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture.

Comment: I don't want the parent view to be aware that the modal is open or not though... I would need to have a flag that says isModalOpen. It doesn't feel right.

Comment: @alexmngn did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

So why are you return true in SubView methods, if you don't want to respond to the gestures. I think you should return false:

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => false,
    onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
});
```

also from the docs:

> So if a parent View wants to prevent the child from becoming responder
>   on a touch start, it should have a onStartShouldSetResponderCapture
>   handler which returns true.

```
View.props.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture: (evt) => true,
View.props.onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: (evt) => true,
```